# Searching for cell value conditionally VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a following problem: I have written a bit of vba to search for certain value in a cell (this value could be in various rows but always same column) and then take the value that's to the right to it. My code seems to have no errors but also does nothing...

Here is what i have:

```
Dim bottomCell As Range
Dim offsetCell As Range
With Sheets("Spółka")
Set bottomCell = .Cells.Find(what:="Wykreślona z KRS?")
Set offsetCell = bottomCell.Offset(0, 1)
End With
If offsetCell.Value = "TRUE" Then
MsgBox "Spółka wykreślona z KRS"
End If
```

So the logic would display the window with some message if the value right to the cell im looking for equals "TRUE". Right now the code seems to be searching but it doesnt display anything...

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score -1):

Try it in the next way, please:

```
Sub testFindCells()
  Dim bottomCell As Range, offsetCell As Range, shSp As Worksheet
  
  Set shSp = Sheets("Spólka")

Set bottomCell = shSp.UsedRange.Find("Wykreslona z KRS?", , xlValues)
                                        
If Not bottomCell Is Nothing Then
    Set offsetCell = bottomCell.Offset(0, 1)
    Debug.Print offsetCell.Address
    If CBool(offsetCell.Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Spólka wykreslona z KRS"
    End If
Else
  MsgBox "Wykreslona z KRS?" & " coluld not be found..."
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but your code is propably missing the part specifying what value should the offset cell have. If its "TRUE" then display message, if not the dont display anything.

Comment: Right sorry I forgot to explain it better, the TRUE value is not a boolean, its text (string). It just says "TRUE". Moreover your code stopped at this line: Set bottomCell = shSp.UsedRange.Cells.Find("Wykreślona z KRS?", _
                shSp.Range("A1"), xlValues, , , xlNext, False), saying that there was an error type 13 "Mismatch"

Comment: @Alwexistwo: Now I understood that, but "stopped at this line" is not so clear... Which line and with what error. I will adapt the code to return the message box in case of 'FALSE' string...

Comment: Adapted the code. If I could understand the meaning of "Spólka wykreslona z KRS", I maybe could understand what is it about... :) Now I can see you posted the line. Is it split on two rows (after " _" the second one...)?

Comment: Yes, when i ran the macro it displays "Run time error: 13, Type mismatch" and when i click "debug" it highlights the line i stated above.

Comment: Please, try write "Spólka" and all the special characters in your language. They maybe could be changed during copy - pasting process. The code works well on my test environment...

Comment: Yes i copy pasted your code exactly as it is. The line break is there.

Comment: @Alwexistwo: Strange... Can you, please, edit your question and add the code you use after your existing one?

Comment: @Alwexistwo: Please, try the modified (shorter) line raising the error...

Comment: @Alwexistwo: Is "TRUE" the value of the cell, or part of a string? Is it inside a formula, a result of a formula? I suppose your code has the line `Set shSp = Sheets("Spólka")` before the problematic one...